# Can not extract resource from com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@405b3f5f

Tags: android

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xaQik.png)https://youtu.be/-vAI7RSPxOA

I followed this video for studying Android Fragment,But when I finished,This error comes up.
How to fix this error??

I did googling but I cannot find the solution.
I think many ParsedResource Error is caused by string , ' or \

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.